# Application event is undefined

Tags: lightning, lightning-events

I don't know what wrong happens is with my Application. Wherever I have written the javascript code to get Application event, it always returns undefined. And my code is just simple as written below.

> var appEvent = $A.get('e.c:EventName');
>   appEvent.fire();   // Here I got appEvent undefined

Comment: Will you please share more info? Perhaps the event that you created, the registerEvent snippet etc.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register your event in your component?

```
<aura:registerEvent name="unused" type="c:EventName"/>
```

[As documented here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_fire.htm)

It also states:

> Use $A.get("e.myNamespace:myAppEvent") in JavaScript to get an
> instance of the myAppEvent event in the myNamespace namespace.

so you need to replace c with your namespace.

Comment: Perhaps you want to add a link to the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_fire.htm

Comment: @Basti,  I already did it.

Comment: @KapilKaushik I edited it, after he  reminded me :)

Comment: @Basti - I already tried this also. Well if we are putting the 'c' instead of namespace then Salesforce replace it with namespace itself.